# Remove bullets from li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a JavaScript beginner, and I am building a little select function. I would like to display my li's with the form of little blocks which when selected are added a different background color.

I am encountering a problem with my ul, I can't remove the bullets to put my elements into a proper line. It displays it in kind of cascade and I can't find out why, even I used list-style-type:none;

Here is my code if you want to take a look:

```js
var part = document.querySelector('#part-list ul');

function clickHandlerPart(e) {
  if (n == 1) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'LI') {
      console.log(e.target);
      if (e.target.className == "addpart") {
        console.log('selected');
        e.target.className = 'removepart';
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#9361bf';
        e.target.style.fontSize = '20px';
        e.target.style.marginLeft = '30px';
        e.target.style.border = '1px solid #fff';
        e.target.style.borderRadius = '4px';
        e.target.style.padding = '10px, 10px, 10px, 10px';
        e.target.style.float = 'left';
        part.appendChild(e.target);
      } else {
        console.log('unselected');
        e.target.className = 'addpart';
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      }
      n++;
      console.log('****************');
    }
  } else {
    n = 1;
    return;
  }
}
part.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerPart);
```

```css
#parts {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#parts h2 {
  text-align: center!important;
}

#parts ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#parts li {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.addpart,
.removepart {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="part-list">
  <h2>Which part(s) have you been working on today?</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Decoratives</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Windows</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Signage Gibela</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Signage Prasa</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Stripes</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Others</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you just need a css `li { display: block; }`

Answer (score 3):

The bullets for the `li` can be controlled by the `list-style` property for the `ul` element.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem solve now:

```js
var part = document.querySelector('#part-list ul');

function clickHandlerPart(e) {
  if (n == 1) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'LI') {
      console.log(e.target);
      if (e.target.className == "addpart") {
        console.log('selected');
        e.target.className = 'removepart';
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#9361bf';
        e.target.style.fontSize = '20px';
        e.target.style.marginLeft = '30px';
        e.target.style.border = '1px solid #fff';
        e.target.style.borderRadius = '4px';
        e.target.style.padding = '10px, 10px, 10px, 10px';
        e.target.style.float = 'left';
        part.appendChild(e.target);
      } else {
        console.log('unselected');
        e.target.className = 'addpart';
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      }
      n++;
      console.log('****************');
    }
  } else {
    n = 1;
    return;
  }
}
part.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerPart);
```

```css
#parts {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#parts h2 {
  text-align: center!important;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#parts li {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.addpart,
.removepart {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="part-list">
  <h2>Which part(s) have you been working on today?</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Decoratives</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Windows</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Signage Gibela</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Signage Prasa</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Stripes</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Others</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the style from the list with the below CSS

```
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was some issue in your css. Please check my solution. I hope this will help.

```js
var part = document.querySelector('#part-list ul');

function clickHandlerPart(e) {
  if (n == 1) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'LI') {
      console.log(e.target);
      if (e.target.className == "addpart") {
        console.log('selected');
        e.target.className = 'removepart';
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#9361bf';
        e.target.style.fontSize = '20px';
        e.target.style.marginLeft = '30px';
        e.target.style.border = '1px solid #fff';
        e.target.style.borderRadius = '4px';
        e.target.style.padding = '10px, 10px, 10px, 10px';
        e.target.style.float = 'left';
        part.appendChild(e.target);
      } else {
        console.log('unselected');
        e.target.className = 'addpart';
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      }
      n++;
      console.log('****************');
    }
  } else {
    n = 1;
    return;
  }
}
part.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerPart);
```

```css
#parts {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#parts h2 {
  text-align: center!important;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#parts li {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="part-list">
  <h2>Which part(s) have you been working on today?</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Decoratives</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Windows</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Signage Gibela</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Signage Prasa</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Stripes</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="addpart">Others</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Coping someone answer is violation there is a policy against it https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @FaizanSadiq are you sure that i've copied any one's answer? Would you please check my solution properly? Specially you can check the css portion to clarify.

Comment: check by yourself you have same answer as me I'm the first one to answer but if its coincidence then no worries

Comment: No, it's not the same, Would you please check again? There are lots of differences in our `css`

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you are styling the id selector `#parts` but you don't have anything in your html with that id. Remove the id and just select the element.

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```